# How do I keep the plotted graph and yaxis aligned when doing stacked subplots with plotly R

Tags: r, plotly

I am trying to produce a stack of plots with plotly R but the plotted lines relative to the zero axis are drifting so that what is zero in the top plot is not zero in the bottom plot. Any ideas how to fix this?

Here is an image of the problem:
[image]

Assume that the top plot is correct (it is: Gaussian random walk around zero). Then notice that in plots 2:4 from the top down the xaxis drifts upwards but the exact same data is used on all plots. Notice on the y-axis that the number 2 is drifting upwards. I feel that this is a simple issue (pretty fundamental - keeping values aligned to data!) so I think I am missing something obvious so would appreciate it if someone could point out my obvious mistake.

I have tried setting `anchor` and `scaleanchor` but this seems to have no effect on the positioning, even when `position = 0` and `anchor = 'free'`.

I have also tried variations on `fixedrange` and `autorange` but again no joy.

Here is a reproducible example:

```
set.seed(2244)
cols <- c('black','red','green','cyan','blue','magenta','yellow','gray')
outlist <- list()
nplots <- c(1,2,3,4)
bounds <- 0
trials <- 0
M <- 1
N <- 50
i <- 1
y <- rnorm(N)
chleaf <- rbinom(N, 1, 0.5)
outmat <- matrix(0, nrow=N, ncol=6)
outmat[,c(1,3)] <- rnorm(dim(outmat)[1]*2, 0, 1)
outmat[,c(2,4)] <- outmat[,c(1,3)]^2
outmat[,c(5,6)] <- y - outmat[,c(1,3)]
for (j in nplots) {
  mgrid <- NULL
  if ( bounds == 1 ) {
    mgrid <- c(min(outmat[,3]-2*sqrt(outmat[,4]))-0.5,
               max(outmat[,3]+2*sqrt(outmat[,4]))+0.5)
  } else {
    mgrid <- c(min(min(outmat[,3]), min(outmat[,5]), min(y))-0.5,
               max(max(outmat[,3]), max(outmat[,5]), max(y))+0.5)
  }
  outlist[[i]] <- plotly::plot_ly() %>%
    plotly::add_trace(x = 1:(M*N), y = outmat[,3], type = 'scatter', mode='lines',
      showlegend=ifelse(i==1, TRUE, FALSE), name=TeX('\\mu_{t|t-1}'),
      line=list(color=cols[1], width=0.5)) %>%
      plotly::add_trace(x = 1:(M*N), y = outmat[,3]+2*sqrt(outmat[,4]),
        type='scatter', mode='markers', color=I(cols[1]), size=0.5,
        showlegend=ifelse(i==1, TRUE, FALSE), name=TeX('\\Sigma_{t|t-1}'),
        marker=list(symbol='cross-thin'), visible=ifelse(bounds==1, TRUE, FALSE)) %>%
      plotly::add_trace(x = 1:(M*N), y = outmat[,3]-2*sqrt(outmat[,4]),
        type='scatter', mode='markers', color=I(cols[1]), size=0.5,
        showlegend=FALSE, marker=list(symbol='cross-thin'),
        visible=ifelse(bounds==1, TRUE, FALSE)) %>%
    plotly::add_trace(x = 1:(M*N), y = outmat[,1], type = 'scatter', mode='lines',
      showlegend=ifelse(i==1, TRUE, FALSE), name=TeX('\\mu_{t|t}'),
      line=list(color=cols[2], width=0.5)) %>%
      plotly::add_trace(x = 1:(M*N), y = outmat[,1]+2*sqrt(outmat[,2]),
        type='scatter', mode='markers', color=I(cols[2]), size=0.5,
        showlegend=ifelse(i==1, TRUE, FALSE), name=TeX('\\Sigma_{t|t}'),
        marker=list(symbol='cross-thin'), visible=ifelse(bounds==1, TRUE, FALSE)) %>%
      plotly::add_trace(x = 1:(M*N), y = outmat[,1]-2*sqrt(outmat[,2]),
        type='scatter', mode='markers', color=I(cols[2]), size=I(5),
        showlegend=FALSE, marker=list(symbol='cross-thin'),
        visible=ifelse(bounds==1, TRUE, FALSE)) %>%
    plotly::add_trace(x = 1:(M*N), y = outmat[,5], type = 'scatter', mode='lines',
      showlegend=ifelse(i==1, TRUE, FALSE), name=TeX('\\hat{y}_{t}'),
      line=list(color=cols[3], width=0.5)) %>%
    plotly::add_trace(x = 1:(M*N), y = outmat[,6], type = 'scatter', mode='lines',
      showlegend=ifelse(i==1, TRUE, FALSE), name=TeX('\\tilde{y}_{t}'),
      line=list(color=cols[4], width=0.5)) %>%
    plotly::config(mathjax='cdn') %>%
    plotly::layout(
      xaxis=list(title=list(text='Iterations', standoff=0),
          showline=T, showgrid=F, range = c(0, ifelse(N==1, M+0.25, N*M+0.5)),
          anchor='y', scaleanchor='x'),
      yaxis=list(showline=T, showgrid=F, range=mgrid))

  rMe <- 0
  for (n in 1:N) {
    rMe <- rMe+M
    nchleaf <- (M*(n-1)+1):(n*M)*chleaf[(M*(n-1)+1):(n*M)]
    xupdates <- nchleaf[which(nchleaf!=0)]
    yupdates <- as.vector(sapply(y[n], function(x){rep(x,length(xupdates))}))
    outlist[[i]] <- outlist[[i]] %>%
    plotly::add_trace(x = c(M*(n-1), n*M), y = c(y[n], y[n]),
      type = 'scatter', mode='lines',
      showlegend=ifelse((i==1 && n==1), TRUE, FALSE), name='y',
      line=list(color = cols[6], dash = ifelse(M==1, 'solid', 'dash'),
                width=0.5)) %>%
    plotly::add_trace(x = xupdates, y = yupdates,
      type='scatter', mode='markers',
      showlegend=ifelse((i==2&&n==1), TRUE, FALSE), name='Update',
      color=I(cols[5]), size=0.5) %>%
    plotly::add_trace(x = rMe, y = mgrid,
      type = 'scatter', mode='lines', visible=ifelse(trials==1, TRUE, FALSE),
      showlegend=ifelse((trials==1 && i==1 && n==1), TRUE, FALSE), name='Trial',
      line=list(color = cols[8], dash = 'dash', width=0.5))
  }
  i <- i+1
}
fig <- plotly::subplot(outlist, nrows=length(nplots), shareX=TRUE,
                       which_layout=c(1)) %>%
  plotly::config(staticPlot=T, mathjax='cdn', displayModeBar = F)
fig <- fig %>% plotly::layout(
    showlegend=TRUE,
    legend=list(itemsizing='trace', orientation='h', xanchor='center', x=0.5),
    margin=list(b=70, l=45, r=30, t=80),
    title=list(text="Test Title"))
      # yaxis=list(autorange=TRUE, fixedrange=FALSE))
      # xaxis=list(anchor='y', scaleanchor='x'),
      # yaxis=list(anchor='x', scaleanchor='y'))
      # yaxis=list(range=mgrid))#,
      # xaxis=list(title=list(text='Iterations', standoff=0),
      #     showline=T, showgrid=F, range = c(0, ifelse(N==1, M+0.25, N*M+2))),
      # yaxis=list(showline=T, showgrid=F))
```

Comment: Are the y values or x values wrong?

Comment: Neither. As the title says, the plotted lines are not aligned with the Yaxis values. If you look at the image you will see this is the case. I think it is a scaling issue but I don't know how to fix it.

Comment: In the plot pane the image is right but when i try to save it i get the same error. How are you saveing to png?

Comment: I use this `html21 <- paste0("html/ps",21,".html")
img21 <- paste0("images/ps",21,".png")
htmlwidgets::saveWidget(widget = ps21, file = html21)
webshot(url = html21, file = img21)`. But it doesn't matter. Either as `.png` or as simple export from Rstudio viewer, the same problem persists.

Comment: What backend are you using ? the error only occures if i use AGG , Cairo works fine ,

Comment: I have tried Cairo, Cairo PNG and AGG. Same issue in all of them.

Comment: Also restarted Rstudio and R and tried again with no joy.

Comment: what happens if you use default margins b=80, l=80, r=80, t=100 ?

Comment: Tried that. No change. Note that when I try to "Export" from RStudio "Viewer" my image does not re-scale at all. i.e. It does not do what your giff does at all.

Answer (score 0):

Its a bug in the backend of the graphics device ( or similar) . if you touch the scale knob in the export window the scales jump to the right position.

[image]

This is a workaround, i think plotly is not the ideal choice for static images since it translates to python using reticulate and its also more focused on dynamic web stuff. So i would not expect a quick bugfix.

Comment: Hi. You are right about plotly for dynamic plots but your solution doesn't work. I think there must be something simple for fixing scales. As I say, it is pretty fundamental and plotly is pretty comprehensive.

Comment: Did you try to move the scale knob as in the gif?

Comment: Yup. Done that. However, a) my device did not scale the object as your gif shows and b) I cannot honestly believe that people as professional as plotly developers would rely on "knob twiddling" for plot outputs. Besides, there is a bigger issue because I need to generate plots in rmarkdown and I need guaranteed consistency ( as I am sure plotly developers know).

Comment: A) the problem is not in the R code butr in the backend you are using. B) plotly is written in javascript and mainly used with python so  most people are not using RStudio but some python IDE , and there goal is not to create static images but js / html

Comment: A) Tried all backend options, none worked. B) Mostly true however producing static plots is a function they offer and, like I said, these people are pretty professional so I guess the solution is still out there ...